# Camel Web service message consumer

Tags: web-services, apache-camel, cxf

I am trying to build an xml spring-based camel web service consumer using apache cxf endpoint similar to the example here...

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="soapMessageEndpoint"
                 serviceClass="org.apache.camel.example.cxf.provider.GreeterProvider"
                 address="http://localhost:9000/GreeterContext/SOAPMessageService"
                 wsdlURL="wsdl/hello_world.wsdl"
                 endpointName="s:SoapOverHttpRouter"
                 serviceName="s:SOAPService"
                 xmlns:s="http://apache.org/hello_world_soap_http"/>


<camelContext id="test_context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <route>
    <from uri="cxf:bean:soapMessageEndpoint"/>
    <to uri="bean:testBean?method=processSOAP"/>
  </route>
</camelContext>
```

The web service already exists, but I'm not interested in setting up and exposing a client like in the example.  Under normal operation clients would subscribe to the web service and the web service in turn publishes out events to the subscribers periodically.
I have a simulator that generates the web service messages automatically already and I just want to consume the web service message in my camel route and log it, so I don't need to process it or do something with the messages.
I just want my endpoint to act as a listener/sniffer for these messages as they are published therefore I don't really need a service class.

What's the easiest or most efficient way to set this up in camel?  Maybe cxf is the wrong component to be leveraging here. The web service is using SOAP.

Comment: `web service in turn publishes out events to the subscribers` this is how messaging works or web sockets, but not web services over soap..  web services are using request/response pattern.. or you should make clear what is a service and what is a client (consumer)

Comment: True, but I can certainly register with a callback address for the web service to send events. Whether the web service deals with the response from the client or not is up to him. In my example I have a simulator pushing out these these events, not a web service, albeit they are still in an http/soap form. I just need to consume them.

Comment: Looks like I just need to build a service implementation class to receive the messages.